# Django REST with remote jwt authentication

Tags: django, api, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt

I'm going to create a Django REST project that have to be remote users: an external server exposes authentication api and uses **JWT**. It exposes to me also a bearer token to permit me to use apis.
My Django will have to expose api for authentication for the clients (mobile apps).
I don't have much clear in my mind how to handle the authentication flux: do I have to build a custom authentication?